# La ventana popup o modal no aparece con HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, web, modal, popup

He creado un diseño web con *HTML* y *CSS* para lo cual quiero que se muestre una ventana *popup* o *modal*; Mi consulta viene porque no se muestra la ventana *modal* o *popup* al hacer clik en **LEER MAS**. A continuación muestro el código cargado en *GitHub*:

https://github.com/memo15428/Rep_proyecto_html_css/blob/master/tesis.html
https://github.com/memo15428/Rep_proyecto_html_css/blob/master/css/estilos_todo_public.css

Asimismo, adjunto algo de código referente a lo que desee obtener:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'open sans';
}
.contenedor {
    padding: 35px 0;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.titulo {
    color: #F7B733;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.arriba {
    padding-top: 0;
}

/*Encabezado*/
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: rgba(74,189,172,0.73);
    background: linear-gradient(92deg,rgba(74,189,172,0.73) 0%, rgba(74,189,172,0.8) 80%), url(../img/enca_1.jpg);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,rgba(74,189,172,0.73) 0%, rgba(74,189,172,0.8) 80%), url(../img/enca_1.jpg);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(92deg,rgba(74,189,172,0.73) 0%, rgba(74,189,172,0.8) 80%), url(../img/enca_1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
figure .logo {
    width: 12%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
.menu_principal {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;    
}
.menu_1 {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_1 a {
    list-style: none;
    color: seashell;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_1:hover{
    background: rgba(178, 141, 71, .28);
}
.submenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 111px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    border: 4px;
    background: rgba(178, 141, 71, .1); 
}
.submenu:hover {
    background: rgba(178, 141, 71, .1);
    transition: background .5s ease-out;
}
#menu_principal ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
#menu_principal ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.ola_img_enca {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
header .frase_enca {
    display: flex;
    height: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
.frase_enca h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.frase_enca h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/*Todos Publicaciones*/
/*Estilos Base*/
.contenedor-img {
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
.tesis_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff;

}
.tesis_box .mascara,.tesis_box .contenido {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.tesis_box img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.tesis_box h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    background:RGBA(96,99,100,0.73);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
.tesis_box p {
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tesis_box a.link_popup {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: RGBA(96,99,100,0.73);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000
}
.tesis_box a.link_popup:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}

/*Ejemplo 1*/
.tesis img {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.tesis .mascara {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(74,189,172,0.73);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.tesis h2 {
    transform: translateX(-200px);/*Desplazamos a la izquierda*/
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.tesis p {
    transform: translateX(200px);/*Desplazamos a la derecha*/
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
.tesis a.link_popup{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(100px)/*Desplazamos para abajo*/
}
.tesis:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);/*Damos un ligero zoom a la imagen*/
}
.tesis:hover .mascara {
    opacity: 1;
}
.tesis:hover h2,
.tesis:hover p,
.tesis:hover a.link_popup {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);/*Regresamos a las posiciones originales*/
}
.tesis:hover p {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.tesis:hover a.link_popup {
    transition-delay: 0.2s; /*Aplicamos un pequeño retardo para que se muestre al final*/
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

/*Modal*/

.contenedor_popup_modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 600ms;
}
.contenedor_popup_modal:target {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.contenedor_popup_modal:target .ventana_popup_modal {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%, 50%);
    visibility: visible;
}
.ventana_popup_modal {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: wheat;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -80%;
    left: -80%;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-150%, 230%);
    transition: all 600ms;
}
.img_modal {
    width: 40%;
    background-image: url(../img/publicaciones/tesis/popup/img_public_tesis_popup_1.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.texto_modal {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.texto_modal h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.texto_modal p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.boton_close_popup {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20%;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GeoFault</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo_gf.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_todo_public.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="encabezado_general">
        <section class="menu">
            <figure>
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo_gf.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
            </figure>
            <nav id="menu_principal">
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu_1"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_1"><a href="publicacion.html">Publicaciones</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_1"><a href="#">Descargas</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_1"><a href="#">Comparte</a>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="proyecto.html"><li class="submenu">Proyectos</li></a>
                            <a href="investigacion.html"><li class="submenu">Investigaciones</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_1"><a href="#">Acerca de</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
        <section class="frase_enca">
            <h1>Bienvenido a GeoFault</h1>
            <h2>...Buenas publicaciones</h2>
        </section>
        <div class="ola_img_enca" style="height: 90px; overflow: hidden;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" 
            preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <path d="M0.00,49.99 C160.46,143.58 349.21,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" 
            style="stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path></svg></div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="contenedor-img">  
            <div class="tesis_box tesis">
                <img src="img/publicaciones/tesis/img_public_tesis_1.jpg" />  
                <div class="mascara">  
                    <h2>Mecánica de suelos y diseño geotécnico de cimentaciones para puentes</h2>  
                    <p>Este documento tiene como objetivo general describir las actividades que se realizarán 
                        dentro del estudio para obtener suficientes criterios geológicos y geotécnicos... </p>
                    <a href="#modal" class="link_popup">Leer mas</a>
                    <div class="contenedor_popup_modal" id="modal">
                        <div class="ventana_popup_modal">
                            <div class="img_modal"></div>
                            <div class="texto_modal">
                                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat deleniti 
                                    tempore, itaque esse natus harum quos possimus reiciendis ratione sequi?</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut nobis id placeat 
                                    harum, distinctio voluptatum debitis, veritatis aut voluptate magni aliquid 
                                    iusto quasi ipsa non et eaque iure eveniet expedita.</p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="boton_close_popup">X</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Al parecer el _modal_ se encuentra debajo del footer, donde no se observa.

Comment: Cuando haces click en pagina completa del snippet, se visualiza el enlace "LEER MAS"